# Share folder not work

Tags: shared-folders, sharing

I followed this 2 guides to share folder on ubuntu 20.10 (last version):

https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/sharing-files-between-ubuntu-and-windows-systems-with-samba/

https://manjaro.site/how-to-share-a-folder-in-ubuntu-20-10/

My computer (windows 10) keep asking me the password and not accept the correct one..

Why?

Comment: Hello. Question needs more info. What version of Ubuntu? What window keeps asking for the password? What command are you running?

Comment: @David I updated the question
Windows 10
Ubuntu 20.10 (last version)